# How I can set custom model fields order in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use django and drf. For example i have such model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = ...
    name = ...
    author = ...
    page_count = ...
```

I use drf and recive such response:

```
{
  "id": ...,
  "name": ...,
  "author": ...,
  "page_count": ...,
}
```

Can i set custome order for fields?

Example:

```
{
  "id": ...,
  "page_count": ...,
  "author": ...,
  "name": ...,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set order of the fields directly in the `serializer`, for example:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'page_count', 'author', 'name')
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I set such order global  for for model? I need have such order everywhere where I use this model (admin for example).

Comment: Just move your fields in correct order inside the model.

Comment: This is a good option, but I use abstract models and supplement them with my data. Sometimes I need augmented data to go before abstract data. I also cannot change the order of data in an abstract model.

Comment: Right, I've also been looking for a way to modify the order even after inheriting an abstract model. It seems like it is not possible. Closest to a solution I've seen so far is modifying the migration files after creation.